# Compare static list to a related dynamic list

Tags: apex

I have a custom object "Involvement". On the Involvement there is a related list called "Extras". These "Extras" have a lookup field to "Products (Product2)".

We have it setup that customers can purchase "Extras", and it links to a standard Product. I want to list the "Extras" they have purchased, while *only* list the available "Extras/Products" they have yet to purchase.

I think I have it right, but I'm getting an error I don't understand.

EDIT, have updated code from @Derek F

```
public with sharing class TSVExtras {

@AuraEnabled 
public static List <Extras__c> getExtras(Id invID) {
    return[SELECT Id,Name, Involvement__c, Product__r.Name,Product__r.Photo__c
           FROM Extras__c 
           WHERE Involvement__c = :invID
          ];
}

@AuraEnabled
public List <Product2> products = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2];

 @AuraEnabled
public static List<Id> getProductsLessExtras(){
List<Id> l = new List<Id>();
Map<Id,Extras__c> ext = new Map<Id,Extras__c>();
for(Extras__c purext : getExtras) // ERROR Variable does not exist: getExtras
{

    ext.put(purext.Product__r.Id,purext);
}
for(Product2 p :  products) //ERROR Variable does not exist: products
{

    if(ext.get(p.Id) == null)
    {
        l.add(p.Id);    
    }

}
System.debug('~~~ Non matching Ids '+ l);
return[SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id in: products]; //ERROR Variable does not exist: products
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public with sharing class TSVExtras {

    @AuraEnabled 
    public static List<Extras__c> getExtrasForInvolvment(Id involvementId) {
        // Add Product__r.Id to SELECT query so we can check it later
        return [
            SELECT Id, Name, Involvement__c, Product__r.Id, Product__r.Name, Product__r.Photo__c, Price__c, 
            Product__r.Description, Product__r.Portal_Name_Price__c, Involvement__r.Days_until_Start__c  
            FROM Extras__c
            WHERE Involvement__c = :involvementId 
            ORDER BY Name ASC
        ];
    }

    // Change the return type to be a List<Product2> instead of List<Id>
    // Note: We must give this method an involvementId so it knows which products to filter for
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Product2> getProductsLessExtras(Id involvementId) {
        // Create list to store purchased product ids
        List<Id> purchasedProductIds = new List<Id>();

        // Call getExtrasForInvolvment(involvementId) method to get list of related extras and put all Product ids into list
        for (Extras__c extra : getExtrasForInvolvment(involvementId)) {
            purchasedProductIds.add(extra.Product__r.Id);
        }

        // Query for all products excluding those in list of purchased products
        return [
            SELECT Id, Name, Description,  Photo__c, Price__c, Portal_Name_Price__c 
            FROM Product2
            WHERE Id NOT IN : purchasedProductIds
            ORDER BY Name ASC
        ];
    }

 //For Creating an Extra__c record attached to a product.   
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string createPurchasedExtra(Extras__c extraobj){
        system.debug('extra: ' + extraobj.Name);
        insert extraobj;
        return extraobj.Id;

    }


    // For removing "Purchased" Extra
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string deletePurchasedExtra(Extras__c extrapur){
        system.debug('extra: ' + extrapur.Name);
        delete extrapur;
        return extrapur.Id;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from class variables/properties, and static initialization blocks, all of the code inside a class needs to be contained inside of a method.

`for(Extras__c purext : getExtras)` is the first line that actually runs afoul of that.

You probably meant to write something like

```
public class MyClass{
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static List <Extras__c> getExtras(Id invID) {
        // your existing code for this method
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public List <Product2> products = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2];

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Id> getProductsLessExtras(){
        List<Id> l = new List<Id>();
        // The rest of your code for this section

        // Don't forget to return a value at the end
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to apex class writing and I copied almost verbatim from another Stack post and I thought it was weird there wasn't a method container but just went with it. What would my return look like?

Return [Id, Name, Photo__c from Product2 where Id in: L]
???

Comment: have updated the post with your solution, but I'm getting 3 variable errors.

Comment: @DCole You need to define variables (and put something into them) before using them. If you haven't gone through [apex basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database) and [apex coding skills](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-apex-coding-skills) on trailhead yet, I'd recommend doing so. Having a firm grip on the fundamentals of OOP (object-oriented programming) is important to understanding the answers you'll get and becoming more skilled as a programmer.